# Getting sinatra and the sitemap_gererator gem to play together nicely

Tags: ruby, activerecord, sinatra, sitemap

The sitemap_generator gem to *successfully* creates and uploads a sitemap for the **static** pages of the app to an Amazon S3 bucket.

Now I'd like to instruct the gem to include each article from my article model **dynamically**.

**This is the error I get:**

```
rake aborted!
wrong constant name #<Class:0x007f80d5858b00>
```

So, just to be clear, the only issue I am having is trying to get the sitemap_generator gem to play nicely with the article model.

**I am using the following gem versions:**
Ruby 1.9.3
Sinatra v 1.4.4
sinatra-activerecord 1.5
sitemap_generator 5.0.1

**config/sitemap.rb:**

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'
require 'sinatra/base'
require 'sinatra/activerecord'
require './config/environments'
require 'sitemap_generator'
require 'carrierwave'
require './config/initializers/carrierwave'

class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
end

SitemapGenerator::Sitemap.default_host = "http://www.mywebsite.com"
SitemapGenerator::Sitemap.public_path = 'tmp/'
SitemapGenerator::Sitemap.adapter = SitemapGenerator::WaveAdapter.new
SitemapGenerator::Sitemap.sitemaps_host = "http://#{ENV['S3_BUCKET']}.s3.amazonaws.com/"
SitemapGenerator::Sitemap.sitemaps_path = 'sitemaps/'

SitemapGenerator::Sitemap.create do

  # This part WORKS.
  add '/company', :changefreq => 'weekly', :priority => 0.9
  add '/team', :changefreq => 'weekly', :priority => 0.9
  add '/services', :changefreq => 'weekly', :priority => 0.9
  add '/blog', :changefreq => 'weekly', :priority => 0.9
  add '/contact', :changefreq => 'weekly', :priority => 0.9

  # This part DOESN'T work.
  Article.find_each do |article|
    add "/blog/#{article.url}", :lastmod => article.updated_at
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

I simply had to add Class:: before declaring and using the Article class.

**Updated code:**

```
class Class::Article < ActiveRecord::Base
end

SitemapGenerator::Sitemap.create do
  Class::Article.find_each do |article|
    add "/blog/#{article.url}", :lastmod => article.updated_at
  end
end
```